# Problems on Qt on NetBeans

Tags: qt, netbeans

After having solved a Qt configured problem on my system, I have now installed NetBeans and everything is OK. It is just that I have the following problem. Here is the code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtDebug>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foreach(QFileInfo  drive,QDir::drives()){
        qDebug()<<"Drive: "<<drive.absolutePath();
        QDir dir=drive.dir();
        dir.setFilter(QDir::Dirs);
        foreach(QFileInfo rootDirs,dir.entryInfoList())

        qDebug()<< " "<<rootDirs.fileName();
    }
    return 0;
   // return app.exec();
}
```

and errors are

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
/usr/bin/qmake VPATH=. -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/qt-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/QtApplication_1
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -Inbproject -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -Inbproject -I. -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Qt1.o Qt1.cpp
Qt1.cpp:7: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’
Qt1.cpp:7: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
g++  -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/QtApplication_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Qt1.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o    -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1/main.cpp:10: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Qt1.o:/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1/Qt1.cpp:7: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/QtApplication_1] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to that output, you are compiling two source files `Qt1.cpp` and `main.cpp`, both of which define the function `main()`. You need to remove one of those two files from your project or remove the definition of `main()` from one of them.

As an added step to get rid of the warning about unused parameters in main(), change it to

```
main(int /*argc*/, char **/*argv*/)
```

until you need to use those arguments.